# python multiprocessing dynamically created processes and pipes

Tags: python, pipe, multiprocessing

I want to be able to dynamically create child processes and pipes between the parent and child elements based on an input file which defines the child.

I can create child processes but i need to be able to create pipes to communicate to a specific node and use those pipes to send specific processing data:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    t = mp.Process(name="transactor", target=t, args=("transaction.csv",))
    nodes = [mp.Process(name=str(n), target=f, args=(n,)) for n in nodeArray]

    for node in nodes:
        node.start()
```

My issue lays in the fact that I do not understand that if the number of processes created could change how can you create a variable number of pipes and select the correct pipe to communicate with if you only know the target node or childs identity?

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to python and I see lots of good examples of using Pythons mulitprocessing library for simple parent child processes and pipes but nothing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Pipe when you create the Process, and return a tuple of the Process an Pipe.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def mkproc(func):
    parent_conn, child_conn = mp.Pipe()
    p = mp.Process(func, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    return (p, parent_conn)
```

After calling `mkproc` to create processes, store the result in a list;

```
allprocs = [mkproc(f) for f in (foo, bar, baz)]
```

The contents of `allproc` is now a list of (`Process`, `Pipe`) tuples. If you iterate over the list you have the process and the pipe that belongs with it;

```
for proc, conn in allprocs:
    # do something with the process or pipe.
```

Comment: Thank you Roland. I think I understand what you are trying to achieve here but I find I encounter the error: `assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'`

Comment: I have subsequently applied this to my actual code and have found it operates well.